# is there a way to create a Podfile in my flutter project using android studio?

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, flutter, podfile

I'm trying to add firebase to my flutter project
I'm using windows machine so I did add it to the android level app while I'm trying to add it to the IOS level app I can't find a way to create the PodFile can someone please help?
as well I don't have access to a mac right now

Comment: If you were able to solve the problem, please consider closing the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well I just solved the problem by navigating to the project file via CMD and to the ios file then typing pod init